# First order PDE in complex variables?

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, cv.complex-variables

Consider the equation

$$f'(x)+ g(x)f(x)=0$$

This equation is an ODE and has a solution $$ f(x)=C e^{ \int_1^x g(x) \ dx}.$$

Similarly, we can look at complex variables and consider the equation and Wirtinger derivatives

$$ (\partial_{\bar z} f)(z) +g(z) f(z)=0.$$

Can one still write down an explicit solution?

Comment: Is $f(z)$ analytic? If so then the derivative of $f(z)$ with respect to $\bar{z}$ does not exist unless $f(z)$ is a constant.

Comment: No, it is not analytic...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can start by looking at the [chain rule for wirtinger derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivatives), from which you deduce that

$$
\partial_{\bar z} \exp(h(z)) = \exp(h(z)) \cdot \partial_{\bar z} h(z)
$$

Therefore, if you find a function $h$ such that $\partial_{\bar z} h = - g(z)$ (I think you forgot a "$-$" sign in your solution for the real case!) taking $f(z) =  \exp(h(z)) $ will solve your problem. In general, this is known as the [d-bar problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBAR_problem) (or $\bar\partial-$problem). As Daniele points out this [Q&A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3125765/let-h-mathbbc-to-mathbbc-in-ck-mathbbc-with-compact-support-find) is a god resource for the $\bar\partial-$problem in 1 dimension.

Comment: @Sascha, Jaume for a solution of the $1$-dim $\bar\partial$-problem [this Q&A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3125765/let-h-mathbbc-to-mathbbc-in-ck-mathbbc-with-compact-support-find) may be relevant.

Comment: Indeed @daniele-tampieri! That's a way better link to the $\bar \partial$ problem than the wikipedia page that has (surprisingly?) almost no reference